# How to display an image in Xamarin Forms for an iOS build

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

This question appears to be simple but it is not.

I have a background image that I want an app to have. I looked online and followed tutorials on how to set everything up. In the android project, I have the image in the drawable folder. In the iOS project, I created an Image set and added my image to the 1x position.

Everything seems good. In the constructor of my main form, I have this line of code:

```
    this.BackgroundImageSource = (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android) ? ImageSource.FromFile("SADBackground.png") : ImageSource.FromFile("Images/SADBackground.png");
```

I run on Android, the image appears. I run on iOS, and there is no background image. Thus begins my Google search. I have tried many different combinations. Removing the png from SADBackground.png. Creating another Image set titled SADBackground. I have tried FromResource. I even tried embedding the image in the iOS project.

Literally everything that I have tried is not working. No matter what I do, I do not get a background image on my iOS app.

Has anyone ran into this issue before? I feel like that I ma missing some sort of setting that I need to set that the tutorials are not telling me about.

Edit:

Here is the currrent implementation of the class that I am using:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BackgroundImageSource = (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android) ? ImageSource.FromFile("SADBackground.png") : ImageSource.FromFile("BackgroundSAD");

        }
}
```

In my asset catalog, I have the name of the image set as BackgroundSAD and the name of the file is SADBackground.png. Now I am not sure if this matters of if they should be the same. I did try making both of the names the same and it still did not work.

I also ran the debugger and looked at the output window, when this line is executed, no message is produced.

The image's resolution is 1440x2880

Edit 2:

I changed the resolution to match that of the iPhone 8 that I am using and still no image being displayed.

This is starting to get ridiculous.

Comment: if you place the images properly for each platform you should not need to specify different paths.  See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

Comment: also, the old-school iOS approach of just putting images in Resources should still work

Comment: Yes, it should work, however, it does not. i even tried that and still couldn't get anything to display

Comment: What is the equivalent Xamarin.Forms code for this: MonkeyImage.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("PurpleMonkey"); 

I am asking because the MS document says this is how to reference the image when in the asset catalog.

Comment: have you looked at the sample apps to compare what they're doing to what you are?  `ImageSource.FromFile()` should be the equivalent

Comment: You are running under debugger, right?  In Output, there is probably an error message telling you it doesn't find that file. Or some other error message? If so, what is it? That's first place to look when there is a problem. In Solution Explorer, select the file. (It is included in the iOS project, in "Images" folder, right?) In Properties, Build action "BundleResource". That includes the file in the bundle. (Or if you wish to access via a `Resource` call, use "EmbeddedResource".)

Comment: Could it be a resolution limit? The resolution of the image is 1440x2880

Comment: I have updated the question with some more info

Comment: I even created an interface so that I can execute some code on the iOS to grab the file path of the image, placed this file path in with ImageSource.FromFile and it still does not work! How are in the world are you suppose to display images with Xamarin????? Should be simple

Comment: Please confirm that in Properties for the image files in the iOS project's Resources folder, the Build Action is set to BundleResource, and note that you SHOULD include the extension, i.e. ImageSource.FromFile("BackgroundSAD.png")  , and if it is in a sub-folder of the Resources folder, it should be added to the path.

Comment: For the image, the Build Action is BundleResource. I have it directly in the folder called Resources. There is no sub folder. and I do include the extension of .png